# CSS background image issue | Inline CSS style property url() not resolving image | background-image:url()

Tags: 2011, 2013, templating, dwt

While defining style properties inline in DWT code , the Default Finish Actions TBB ( Containing Link Resolver TBB ) was NOT able to resolve the url of image contained in style property: 
`background-image:url(@@Components.Fields.ProductListBackgroundImage@@)`.

Below is the DWT code:

```
  <div class="ProductsSectionBackground" 
       style="background-image:url(@@Component.Fields.ProductListBackgroundImage@@)>
  <h3>Products</h3></div>
  <img src="@@Component.Fields.BrandImage@@"/>
```

More surprising, even using Single / Double Quotes inside the image:url() as 
`image:url("@@Component.Fields.ProductListBackgroundImage@@")` and `image:url('@@Component.Fields.ProductListBackgroundImage@@')` even didn't help and still the Output had TcmURI only as :

```
<!-- when using NO Quotes inside url() -->
style="background-image:url(tcm:218-154235)">
<!-- when using Single Quotes inside url() -->
style="background-image:url('tcm:218-154235')"> 
<!-- when using Double Quotes inside url() -->
style="background-image:url("tcm:218-154235")">
```

The **SECOND ISSUE** is that images contained inside such style properties are NOT  pushed onto Package also.

With further searching / lots of code tryouts / looking through the implementation of Default Finish Actions TBB, Link Resolver TBB, the observations / findings were really surprising for me .

***I have shared my complete findings and Solutions to these issues on my  Blog here:*** https://rcnitesh.wordpress.com/2015/04/16/css-background-images-issue-in-tridion-with-inline-style/

However, I am still wondering if there is any better solution/approach to the above mentioned issues and need your inputs.

**Specifically looking for clarifications on** :

1.) The Link Resolver TBB  uses the regex:

```
"{[^}]+url\\s*\\([^\"']*[\"|'](?<tcmuri>tcm:[^\"']+)[\"|']\\s*\\)\\s*;?.*}"
```

for searching CSS style patterns. Why it makes mandatory to use either the Single or Double Quotes in `:url()` ?? [***W3C standard***](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#uri) mentions use of Quotes as optional.

2.) Why the Regex is using curly braces { and } at the very start and end ? It should have been using ( and ) actually.
[image]
 What I found is that it was the use of Curly braces only that ***even if the `image:url()` contained Single or Double Quotes, The Link Resolver is NOT Resolving these CSS style images***.

After replacing these Curly braces with ( and ), image URLs were resolved perfectly.

3.) OR the above points are simply a bug in tridion ? A bug because atleast
    point 2 should have been working without modifying the Regex.

[ Please refer to the [**blog url**](https://rcnitesh.wordpress.com/2015/04/16/css-background-images-issue-in-tridion-with-inline-style/), also mentioned earlier,  if the above points are confusing. I have discussed in full details these points together with screenshots and shared the Solution / Code as well which finally resolves CSS style images issue together with the corrections to be made in Link Resolver TBB ]

[ This issue exists in Tridion 2011 SP1 and possibly in 2013 too ]

**Final NOTE:**

I understand the such CSS Style properties: `background-image:url()` should be specified in CSS file and NOT inline in DWT , But my requirement was such that I did NOT wanted to restrict client in any way from always uploading a fixed name background image whenever it needs to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the regex was not designed for style attibutes, but rather for parsing CSS, since it matches on:

```
{ ... url(["|']tcm:...["|']);... }
```

If you consider this a defect, you should actually report it to Customer Support, else you can create your own TBB with a different regex indeed.

Comment: Thanks Bart. The regex was being used to parse the Output item as found, which will obviously not work. When you say "parse CSS" does this means an actual css file like style.css? In this case I don't think we write url('tcm: inside such files. Please correct me so I can understand further

Comment: Indeed a stylesheet, in case you would publish a style.css Page and the content for that comes from a Component

Comment: Ok, so this regex was meant for css parsing . is there any existing  template in tridion that can resolve these inline css  style property images in DWT ?

Comment: No this is the only one, like I said, you can try to report it as a defect or use your own TBB

Comment: Yes, for TCM Uris in CSS files, we normally wouldn't write them manually. Uploading an HTML page (renamed with extension .dwt), its CSS files, and images using WebDAV (maybe twice to resolve everything) will make the images managed, though. I doubt many implementations do this, but the feature is probably why the TBB parses TCM Uris in CSS (or vice versa in terms of why it works). :-)

Comment: @AlvinReyes I think this feature in the TBB was indeed designed for that demo scenario we used in R5.3 when it just came out.